# Firestore where query cannot change condition in runtime

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on my Flutter app and I am using Firebase as backend. I am also using firestore as my database.

I have this problem that I want to filter out some item, based on user´s selection. I defined variable `filteredCategory` in my DataService and create setter here aswell.

```
void setFilteredCategory(String category) {
    filteredCategory = category;
}
```

Then I called this setter from filter widget

```
DataService().setFilteredCategory(category);
```

But nothing changed in the `where()` method. It just ignored the change.

```
Stream<dynamic> get getItems {
    return items
        .document(uid)
        .collection("items")
        .where("category", isEqualTo: filteredCategory)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_snapshotToUserData);
  }
```

I also tried to set this variable after some time using `sleep()` method and this approach worked, so I dont know, what is wrong here. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try to reasign the items variable. Example var items = items
        .document(uid)
        .collection("items")
        .where("category", isEqualTo: filteredCategory)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_snapshotToUserData);

Comment: Can you please share where your `DataService()` comes from? I can't find any documentation in Dart/Flutter about it or any package.

Comment: @JoãoSoares - DataService is my own service

Comment: How do you use the stream? In a StreamBuilder?

Comment: @Salvatore-Giordano Yes, in StreamBuilder

Comment: The code you shared looks fine. But it is not clear how you're using `getItems`, which is probably where the problem exists. I highly recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it shows the best way to isolate your problem in a way that allows us to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Here is my code on github, if you have time, please check it out. https://github.com/TenPetr/fridgy

Comment: You're using `getItems` in `return StreamBuilder(
      stream: DataService(uid: user.uid).getItems,`. Your `getItems` returns a stream, that stream won't automatically get rebuilt when you change `filteredCategory`. You'll need to update the stream when `filteredCategory` changes, either by recreating the widget, or by building a pipeline, where each time `filteredCategory` changes you yield a new item on the stream.

Comment: On second thought, the proposals from João and imtoori sounds like a better/simpler approach to accomplish the same. Storing the category (or query snapshot) in the state means that Flutter will automatically refresh the stream when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your Stream query isn't changing because it's just being rendered as part of the Widget. Unless you use setState to make sure the query is rebuilt using the new value, it won't change. Try this:

```
void setFilteredCategory(String category) {
  setState((){
    filteredCategory = category;
  });
}
```

If that is not having the result you expect, you can completely move your query from the Widget part and pass it to the state itself.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the stream that the StreamBuilder is using you should put `DataService().setFilteredCategory(category);` inside a `setState` call

```
setState((){
  DataService().setFilteredCategory(category);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new instance of `items` each time like:

```
Stream<dynamic> get getItems {
return Firestore.instance.collection("foo").document(uid).collection("items")
    .where("category", isEqualTo: filteredCategory)
    .snapshots()
    .map(_snapshotToUserData);
```